# Testing Realm in PCL for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, realm

```
RealmConfiguration _configuration = new RealmConfiguration(Path.GetTempFileName());     
var realm = Realm.GetInstance(_configuration);
```

Error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Realms.Realm' threw an exception.
  ----> System.DllNotFoundException : realm-wrappers
```

How do I initialize a realm test database for integration testing in PCL?

Answer (score 0):

[According to documentation](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#does-realm-work-as-a-portable-pcl-library), the PCL library only contains stubs - those methods are not supposed to ever be invoked. You should run your tests in an actual application. If using NUnit, you could make use of the [NUnitLite runner](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NUnitLite-Runner) to create a very simple console runner. Make sure to add references to Realm in the Console Application.

Comment: I am currently using NUnit, is it possible to run in inside Visual studio using the integrated test runner? , This is when I get that error of : System.DllNotFoundException : realm-wrappers

Comment: @B.Afo `using the integrated test runner?`.. No you would need to use a platform-specific runner. There are xUnit/NUnit platform runners for Android/iOS, etc...

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/tree/master/Tests/Tests.NetCore for sample project. Because the test setup is using shared projects, we're only passing `typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly` as the assembly to be run by the `AutoRun`, but if you have tests in PCL assemblies, you should pass those assemblies as well: `new AutoRun(PCLAssembly1, PCLAssembly2,...)`. Still, as @SushiHangover said, tests will be executed by the console application, not by the integrated runner.